# how to send more than 2 emails using php?

Tags: php, email

I want to send two emails at a same time for two different users. I am using php mail function. below is the code.

```
 Send_Mail('abc@example.com,abc2@example.com','Welcome',$message);
```

when I send it to single user, it works fine.But when I add two mail address it didnt work..
Is there any other method is there to solve this???  Help me frnds..

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: What didn't work? Was there any error?

Comment: use loops, for example `foreach` to send each email or just generate header with `CC`

Comment: the mail function is not working for two email address.. thats the problem.@ sankalp mishra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to specify the recipients in the header if you send the email to more than one address.

```
$to = 'abc@example.com' . ', ' . 'abc2@example.com';
$subject = 'Welcome';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: ' . $to . "\r\n";
//$headers .= 'From: Someone <someone@example.com>' . "\r\n";
//$headers .= 'Cc: otherperson@example.com' . "\r\n";
//$headers .= 'Bcc: theotherperson@example.com' . "\r\n";

Send_Mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$recipients = array('abc@example.com','abc2@example.com');
foreach ($recipients as $to) {
    Send_Mail($to,'Welcome',$message);
}
```

OR

```
$to = 'abc@example.com,abc2@example.com';
Send_Mail($to,'Welcome',$message);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$emailArray = array ('abc@example.com','abc2@example.com');
for($i=0;$i<count($emailArray);$i++)
{
Send_Mail($emailArray[$i],'Welcome',$message);
}
```

Now you can send unlimited emails...based on the array data

Comment: This for loop sends only one mail for first recipient and shows "500 Internal server error" @ Sudip Pal

Answer (score 1):

the mail function  works absolutely fine with multiple ids, check out the smtp logs while sending the mail. may be something else is breaking.

for more reference:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Guys, Am getting this error only....  "
500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed." how to solve this?

Comment: hehe the server code is broken. try contacting the recipient domain.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

// multiple recipients

$to  = 'abc@example.com' . ', '; // note the comma

$to .= 'def@example.com';

send_Mail($to, 'Welcome', $message);